# How to replace REGEX as normal text getting from *INI file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file contains `Text.txt`

```
\mathbf{\mathit{adad09}
\mathit{\mathit{aavB}
\mathul{\mathit{AZDs}
```

And I have a `test.ini` file contains (**Since user can add or less the replacements**)

```
<repl>
\mathbf{\mathit{([A-z0-9]*)}    \boldsymbol{\mathit{$1}
\mathit{\mathit{([A-z0-9]*)}    \italicsymbol{\mathit{$1}
\mathul{\mathit{([A-z0-9]*)}    \underlinesymbol{\mathit{$1}
</repl>
```

My Expected output is

```
\boldsymbol{\mathit{adad09}
\italicsymbol{\mathit{aavB}
\underlinesymbol{\mathit{AZDs}
```

My Coding is here

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $myinicnt = ""; my $file = "Test.txt"; my $str = "";
readFileinString($file, \$str); readFileinString("Test.ini", \$myinicnt);
my @replsEach = ();

if($myinicnt=~m/<repl>(.*?)<\/repl>/gs) {  @replsEach = split /\n/, $1;  }
foreach my $myvar( @replsEach )
{
    my ($val1, $val2) = split /\t/, $myvar;
    my $quval1 = quotemeta $val1;

    #First Attempt
    $str=~s{$val1}{$val2}gi;

    #Second Attempt 
    $str=~s{$quval1}{$val2}gi;
}

print $str;

#---------------> File reading
sub readFileinString
#--------------->
{
    my $File = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    open(FILE1, "<$File") or die "\nFailed Reading File: [$File]\n\tReason: $!";
    read(FILE1, $$string, -s $File, 0);
    close(FILE1);
}

#---------------> File Writing
sub writeFileinString
#--------------->
{
    my $File = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    my @cDir = split(/\\/, $File);
    my $tmp = "";
    for(my $i = 0; $i < $#cDir; $i++)
    {
        $tmp = $tmp . "$cDir[$i]\\";
        mkdir "$tmp";
    }
    if(-f $File){
        unlink($File);
    }
    open(FILE, ">$File") or die "\n\nFailed File Open for Writing: [$File]\n\nReason: $!\n";
    print FILE $$string;
    close(FILE);
}
#------------------------- SUB END ------------------------->
```

Error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $val1 in quotemeta at ini.pl line 13.
Use of uninitialized value $val2 in concatenation (.) or string at ini.pl line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $val1 in regexp compilation at ini.pl line 19.
Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\m <-- HERE athbf{\mathit{([A-z]*)}/ a
t ini.pl line 19.
Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\mathbf{\m <-- HERE athit{([A-z]*)}/ a
t ini.pl line 19.
Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\m <-- HERE athit{\mathit{([A-z]*)}/ a
t ini.pl line 19.
Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\mathit{\m <-- HERE athit{([A-z]*)}/ a
t ini.pl line 19.
Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\m <-- HERE athul{\mathit{([A-z]*)}/ a
t ini.pl line 19.
Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\mathul{\m <-- HERE athit{([A-z]*)}/ a
t ini.pl line 19.
\mathbf{\mathit{adad09}
\mathit{\mathit{aavB}
\mathul{\mathit{AZDs}
```

Please could anyone can be guide me to get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the $quval1, you'll see what the problem is:

```
\\mathbf\{\\mathit\{\(\[A\-z0\-9\]\*\)\}
                    ~~~~ ~~  ~~ ~~~~~~
```

[quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) backslashes the dashes, parentheses, square brackets, and asterisks, as well, but you need to keep them unbackslashed.

But, how do you recognize which of these characters are part of a regex and which are part of the TeX markup?

Store the regexes in the file already quoted.

That doesn't end the story, though. The `$1` is the replacement isn't expanded, because it's not contained in the replacement literally. You can use the `/e` switch to evaluate the replacement, but then you need to backslash backslashes in it again, and in fact you need the double `/ee` to evaluate the code properly, so you need to wrap the string in quotes to make it syntactically correct.

Data:

```
<repl>
\\mathbf\{\\mathit\{([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\}    \\boldsymbol{\\mathit{$1}
\\mathit\{\\mathit\{([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\}    \\italicsymbol{\\mathit{$1}
\\mathul\{\\mathit\{([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\}    \\underlinesymbol{\\mathit{$1}
</repl>
```

Code:

```
$val2 = qq("$val2");
$str =~ s/$val1/$val2/geei;
```

I also had to fix the file names, as `Text`, `Test`, and `test` are three different strings.

Comment: You haven't backslashed all the backslashes.